# python 2.6 cPickle.load results in EOFError

Tags: python, pickle, eoferror

I use cPickle to pickle a list of integers, using HIGHEST_PROTOCOL,

```
cPickle.dump(l, f, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

When I try to unpickle this using the following code, I get an EOFError. I tried 'seeking' to offset 0 before unpickling, but the error persists.

```
l = cPickle.load(f)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just noticed that I am not writing to/ reading from the file in binary mode. Hopefully that will fix this issue.

Comment: Obviously I projected that thought to you as I was typing my answer :p

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are on windows, make sure you

```
open(filename, 'wb') # for writing
open(filename, 'rb') # for reading
```

Comment: Thanks, 7 years later, this is still helpful!. helped me alot ;)

Comment: Agreed. Just saved me, too.