# pickle.load() raising EOFError in Windows

Tags: python, windows, file-io, newline, pickle

This is how the code is

```
with open(pickle_f, 'r') as fhand:
    obj = pickle.load(fhand)
```

This works fine on Linux systems but not on Windows. Its showing EOFError.
I have to use `rb` mode to make it work on Windows.. now this isn't working on Linux.

Why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: When you created the pickle object, what OS did you create it on? Linux or Windows? I dont think you could create a pickle object on one  system and load it from other

Comment: @Rush The code was initially written on Linux.. I (new dev) working in windows... but since its a Django project, I generated everything right on my system again..

Comment: @Rush, sure you can. as long as you open files in binary mode on both ends, to avoid newline incompatibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 2.6 cPickle.load results in EOFError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187558/python-2-6-cpickle-load-results-in-eoferror)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Always use `b` mode when reading and writing pickles (`open(f, 'wb')` for writing, `open(f, 'rb')` for reading).  To "fix" the file you already have, convert its newlines using `dos2unix`.

Comment: what do you mean? why would you need `r+b` here?

Comment: I was just trying some mode mentioned in pickle docs :p got tired setting up a production server..

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was because my previously generated file didn’t have the `b` flag when created. Thanks for the hint!