# python anaconda memory error (EOF error)

Tags: python, anaconda

i m a trainee and my work its to integrate a source code with theano (which working fine on linux) on windows 
and here what i do 
first i research hox to install the different biblio on python
i find that anaconda make it easy to do that 
but when i run this code and the file needed  :
http://www.filedropper.com/imagefolderdeeplerningfile_1
i have this error :
http://www.filedropper.com/error_1
if you can help

Comment: i correct the problem by adding rb to pickle.load

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719930/pickle-load-raising-eoferror-in-windows

Comment: i actually need help to make this code executable

Comment: i try to use py2exe and pyinstaller but its say dependeny not found if somone can help