# EOFError using cPickle.load() on windows

Tags: python, pickle

Hi guys so I'm having a bit of a problem, I'm trying to load a file using pickle(code below), this code runs perfectly on my partner's laptop(mac book), but on my laptop it won't run(Windows).

```
strPath = openFileDialog.GetPath()
self.model = cPickle.load(open(strPath, 'rb'))
self.loadModelCombo.SetValue(strPath)
```

After using that code to load the file, I get an EOFError.

```
>File "CMain.py", line 511, in loadModel
>self.model = cPickle.load(open(strPath, 'rb'))
>EOFError
```

Comment: How did you generate the pickle file? Does the write file opened with parameter 'wb' too?

Comment: @PhilipTzou [cPickle.dump(model, open(fullPath, 'w'))] thats the code on how we saved the file, should it have been 'wb' the whole time?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15719966/2644759.

Comment: @PhilipTzou thank you kind sir. :)